# I have panel data, 2 countries over time. But i want to see female/male differences in one of my dependent variables. How?

Tags: regression, panel-data

for my research I am comparing two different countries, overtime. So i am guessing I have panel data. I am putting all my data on Excel first: in this order:
Country (Italy=1,France=0); years ; Dependent variable; All independent variables

One of my independent variables is enrollment. But I want to see the different effects of female and male enrollments. How do I do this? Should i create another dummy variable with male/female or just run two separate regressions with the data for male enrollments and female enrollments?

Answer (score 1):

What is your dependent variable? Enrollment? If so and to mitigate any differences in scale (size of enrollment) that could result in artifactual results, you might want to consider taking the natural log (use the *log* function) of Enrollment before regressing. Then, the key predictor would be the dummy for M/F.

You mention other independent variables. Of course, the challenges with Excel's regression module are multiple, not least of which is an upper limit of 16 predictors -- you might have to be sparing in which ones you use in the model. Not only that, these are limited to continuous variables only, i.e., no categorical or text factors allowed (it's a regression module, not ANOVA). So, qualitative factors such as seasonality or month of the year would require additional dummies.

One of the biggest issues with any time series model is the extent to which the errors are autocorrelated. This can be analyzed visually by requesting predicted *Y* and residual output in the Excel regression dialogue box (or calculate them by hand). Overlay a plot of the predictions (y-axis) with the residuals (x-axis) by country. A visual inspection of the plot should show that the residuals are scattered randomly around zero over time. If not, and there is any observable pattern, e.g., 4 or 5 errors in a row above or below the line, then you will want to get your hands on an introductory time series text to figure out what to do next. This could include a hand-calculation of the Durbin-Watson test statistic but you would still have to look up the test's critical value in a D-W table. There are many solutions for autocorrelation, but some cures are worse than the disease, and all are beyond the scope of this post.

In addition and to make matters worse, a key goal in time series modeling is to reduce the errors or residuals down to white noise (HAC, *heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation consistent*). Excel completely lacks the built-in functionality for testing issues such as autocorrelated errors (Durbin-Watson test, already noted), co-integration (Dickey-Fuller test for several trend-related concerns), much less tests and controls for whitening the residuals or dealing with heteroscedasticity.

Otherwise, I feel your pain in leveraging Excel for any regression analysis whatsoever, much less time series, and I wish you luck. And you thought the answer would be simple, I'm sure. At the end of the day, you can simply ignore everything I wrote after the third paragraph and just push through to an uncomplicated answer. If your audience is sufficiently technically clueless (most audiences are), they won't ask any annoying, pedantic questions and you should be fine, but you're the best judge of that.